# Java basic integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I can't figure out why my outcome is not:

```
Your first array element is: 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

(the expected output)

My code:

```
public class day7 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arrayZ[] = new int[7];

        arrayZ[0] = 0;
        System.out.println("Your first array element is: " + arrayZ[0]);

        int i = 1;
        while (i <= 6){
            arrayZ[i] = i;
            i++;
        System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);
        }
    System.out.println("Each entry of the array is: " + arrayZ[0] + " " + arrayZ[1] + " " + arrayZ[2] + " " + arrayZ[3] + " " + arrayZ[4] + " " + arrayZ[5] + " " + arrayZ[6]);
    System.out.println("And, the sum of all array elements are: " + arrayZ[0] + arrayZ[1] + arrayZ[2] + arrayZ[3] + arrayZ[4] + arrayZ[5] + arrayZ[6]);
    }
}
```

Outcome/actual output:

```
Your first array element is: 0
0
0
0
0
0
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>     at day7.main(day7.java:14)

Comment: call i++; after    System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger (e.g. use IntelliJ IDEA) and you'll see where it goes wrong.

Comment: When you're using `while` looping which relies on an inc/decrement sentinel value (i.e.; `i` in your case) a for loop is generally the more concise option. `for (int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct only problem is in order of `incrementing` and `printing`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arrayZ[] = new int[7];

    arrayZ[0] = 0;
    System.out.println("Your first array element is: " + arrayZ[0]);

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 6)  {
        arrayZ[i] = i;
        System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Each entry of the array is: " + arrayZ[0] + " " + arrayZ[1] + " " + arrayZ[2] + " " + arrayZ[3] + " " + arrayZ[4] + " " + arrayZ[5] + " " + arrayZ[6]);
    System.out.println("And, the sum of all array elements are: " + (arrayZ[0] + arrayZ[1] + arrayZ[2] + arrayZ[3] + arrayZ[4] + arrayZ[5] + arrayZ[6]));
}
```

Also you need to sum the items first so need to use brackets and then using `+` with `String` will convert other variable to `String` and will show the concatenated result. The output is:

> Your first array element is: 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   Each entry of the array is: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
>   And, the sum of all array elements are: 21

If you have fixed bounds for your loop counter (in your case they are 1 to 6) then it is better to make use of `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comment is crystal clear and very helpful.

Comment: You just have to replace by i++ to System.out line ...because its array will bound on last index by i++.

Answer (score 1):

just switch the lines between i++ and System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);

and if you want calculate the sum just add them in a new variable or use ();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arrayZ[] = new int[7];

    arrayZ[0] = 0;
    System.out.println("Your first array element is: " + arrayZ[0]);

    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 6) {
        arrayZ[i] = i;
        System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Each entry of the array is: " + arrayZ[0] + " " + arrayZ[1] + " " + arrayZ[2] + " " + arrayZ[3] + " " + arrayZ[4] + " " + arrayZ[5] + " " + arrayZ[6]);
    System.out.println("And, the sum of all array elements are: " + (arrayZ[0] + arrayZ[1] + arrayZ[2] + arrayZ[3] + arrayZ[4] + arrayZ[5] + arrayZ[6]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
while (i <= 6){
    arrayZ[i] = i;
    System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Because the way you were using it, it tries to print arrayZ[7], that not exists.

Comment: That was what I thought. :3

Answer (score 1):

- just switch the lines between i++ and System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);
- and if you want calculate the sum just add them in a new variable or 
  use ();

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int arrayZ[] = new int[7];

  arrayZ[0] = 0;
  System.out.println("Your first array element is: " + arrayZ[0]);

  int i = 1;
  while (i <= 6) {
      arrayZ[i] = i;
      System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);
      i++;
  }
  System.out.println("Each entry of the array is: " + arrayZ[0] + " " + arrayZ[1] + " " + arrayZ[2] + " " + arrayZ[3] + " " + arrayZ[4] + " " + arrayZ[5] + " " + arrayZ[6]);
  System.out.println("And, the sum of all array elements are: " + (arrayZ[0] + arrayZ[1] + arrayZ[2] + arrayZ[3] + arrayZ[4] + arrayZ[5] + arrayZ[6]));
  ```

  }

Answer (score -1):

change while loop code as follows

```
while (i <= 6){
    arrayZ[i] = i;
    System.out.println(arrayZ[i]);
    i++;
}
```